# how to send escape character without hitting any buttons (send by a command) in vim

Tags: vim, vi

I have many network devices that supports vim and I need to create same file each one of them. I can not use transfer protocols like ftp/sftp so I tried to create with VIM.

So by a script I will send commands something like below. The problem is I can't go the command mode. I couldn't able to emulate esc character. I am testing it just copying below text and paste to ssh session.

```
vi test

i

echo blabla

\0x1B

:WQ
```

I tried instering \0x1B as ESC but it didn't work. Could you help me please?

Comment: If you can use SSH, can you used [`scp`](https://linuxconfig.org/Scp)?

Comment: SCP is an option for sure. But like I said file transfer is not desired for this case. Thanks for advise anyway.

Comment: Can't you simply `echo` the content into the file?

Comment: I agree with others, that echo, sed and awk should do the job. If you really want to do it with vim, just support the commands to vim with the `-c` command line argument.

Comment: maybe I mislead by typing echo. actually it was just an example. there will be a couple of  commands to configure router instead of just an echo. and for reminder that vim is not on linux server. router builtin file server support a version of vim.